# How to have the newest blog post come up at the top of a NextJS blog?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, blogs

I have a Next JS website with a blog page. Everything is set up correctly where on the /blog page is populating the page with slug data. Currently the blog posts on the page come up with the newest posts appearing under older ones. I want to reverse this so when the client uploads a new post, it appears at the top.

HTML

```
<div className='container'>
       {blogs.map(blog => (
          <div className='row blog-content'>
              <div className='col-lg-6 blog-image-body'>
                  <img className='blog-image' src={blog.image} />
              </div>
              <div className='col-lg-6 blog-body'>
                  <div className='blog-card'>
                      <h2 className='blog-date'>{blog.date}</h2>
                      <h1 className='blog-title'>{blog.title}</h1>
                      <div className='main-btn-body'>
                          <Link 
                              className='link-body'
                              rel="noreferrer"
                              href={`/blog/${blog.slug}`}>
                              <button type="submit" className="main-btn">
                              Read Full Post</button>
                          </Link>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

getStaticProps() js code:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  // List of files in blgos folder
  const filesInBlogs = fs.readdirSync('./content/blogs')

  // Get the front matter and slug (the filename without .md) of all files
  const blogs = filesInBlogs.map(filename => {
    const file = fs.readFileSync(`./content/blogs/${filename}`, 'utf8')
    const matterData = matter(file)

    return {
      ...matterData.data, // matterData.data contains front matter
      slug: filename.slice(0, filename.indexOf('.'))
    }
  })

  return {
    props: {
      blogs
    }
  }

}
```

Thanks for any info!

I tried finding any info online but haven't been able to.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = blogs.slice().reverse()
<div className='container'>
       {data.map(blog => (
          <div>
              {blog.name}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

you can try this

Comment: Oh yea, i completely forgot about that! That worked. Thanks!